# Disable specific select field option

Tags: forms, hooks

I'd like to disable an option on a select field (based on a user role). I am doing this inside a form_alter hook. I got the user role condition working fine but I can't seem to disable a select option.

The following lines work but are not the ultimate behavior I'm looking for:

```
// I can unset a select option but this poses a problem
// in the case the value was already chosen by a permitted role.
// But at least I know I can target the option   
unset($form['my_field'][und]['#options'][4]);

// I can disable the whole field.
// Again not quite what I'm looking for but I wanted to be sure the 'disabled' attribute syntax worked.
$form['my_field']['und']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

but not anything along the lines of

```
$form['my_field']['und']['#options'][4]['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
$form['my_field']['und']['#options'][4]['#option_attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
$form['my_field']['und']['#option_attributes'][4]['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Can anyone shed some light on how this might be feasible?

Comment: Drupal does not, out of the box, support the disabled attribute for an option. You could write an override to the template for the field though, using a custom key like '#disabled_options' in the form to tell your template which option(s) to disable.

Comment: Thank you, that helps understand why I struggled so much to get something working. Knowing I can't used disabled on a option value, I'm thinking about still using the 'unset' but checking first to see if that value is selected. (And if it is selected not 'unsetting' it.)